# Will this cause a memory leak in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
int* alloc()
{
    int* tmp = new int;
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr = alloc();
    ......
    ......
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

1. Here I have not freed tmp but ptr is freed explicitly. Will tmp also
   be freed since ptr and tmp refer to the same location?
2. If not then what happens to the pointer tmp? Does it cause a memory leak?

Comment: It doesn't cause a leak. The pointer `tmp` itself is a stack variable, so it doesn't use any memory once `alloc()` returns.

Comment: How is tmp a stack variable when it uses new operator?

Comment: @kishore: `ptr` just holds an address. That address is stored on the stack. What it _points to_ (the resource) is somewhere else, and that's what you need to free (the resource, not the pointer). `delete prt;` doesn't actually do _anything_ to `ptr` itself. Only to what it points to.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: Thanks for the explanation. Now its clear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this does not cause a memory leak. Memory leaks are *buffers* (blocks of memory) that have been allocated but not returned (when they will no longer be used). In your `alloc()` function, `tmp` is not a buffer... it's a variable that, after the call to `new`, holds the *address* of a buffer. Your function returns this address which, in `main()`, gets stored in the `ptr` variable. When you later call `delete ptr`, you are releasing the *buffer* that `ptr` points to, thus the buffer has been released and there is no leak.

Comment: What happens when I have several RAW pointers pointing to the same memory location and free one of those pointers? Is the memory freed then?

Comment: @kishore yes, you must free your buffer exactly once, and it does not matter how many places (pointers) you've got a copy of the buffer's address.

Answer (score 3):

Your program will not cause a memory leak ***provided no uncaught exceptions are thrown***.

You can do better and make it 100% bomb-proof like this:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> alloc()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> tmp { new int };
    //... anything else you might want to do that might throw exceptions
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = alloc();

    // other stuff that may or may not throw exceptions

    // even this will fail to cause a memory leak.
    alloc();
    alloc();
    alloc();

    auto another = alloc();

    // note that delete is unnecessary because of the wonderful magic of RAII
    return 0;
}
```

Get into this habit early.